# Requesting Instant messages between timestamps in a REST api

Tags: java, rest

I have messages that are timestamped when they are sent. Im trying to build an endpoint that can take two datetimes and return all messages that fit inbetween these datetimes. My message timestamps are in Instant format, however im not sure the best approach for the client input.

Currently I have this to request the date, however i need to ability to alter the time aswell:

```
public class MessageRequest {
    private Date timestampBefore;
    private Date timestampAfter;
    ...
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What did you try already? And what issues are you encountering?

Comment: Never use either `Date` class bundled with Java. They are both legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Use `java.time.Instant` class instead.

Comment: Your Question is unclear. And almost certainly a duplicate. The topic of searching within a time frame has been addressed many times. Notice that `Instant` implements `Comparable`, and offers `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods. Also, search for “Half-Open” as an approach in defining a time range. Furthermore, the `Interval` class offered by the `ThreeTen-Extra` library may be useful.